# Web API client organization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a c# web API project that exposes a lot of methods through HTTP and I need to consume it in a c# web mvc application. I use the HttpClient class for this but my question is, how should I organize the access to this web API? for example, the web api project has n controllers, so I could create n IClient interfaces, one per API controller, in the mvc site, or just one big IClient that contains a method for every single API method exposed in the web api project? Is there a preferred approach for this? (that doesn't involve auto generated client code)

Comment: is the api one you created or a 3rd party api?

Comment: Depends on how you are going to consume it. Aligning to the controller layout would be a good start, but may prove to be impractical to consume.

Comment: I created the API. And yes, the "controller layout" sometimes doesn't align well with the way the API is consumed (some operations require using several "controller clients". On the other hand, a single Client is a "bottle neck" with many people developing and having changes on it.